# Android Overlap a moving icon on surfaceview

Tags: android, surfaceview

Do anyone have an idea about overlapping an moving icon on surfaceview.
It's like a cursor on your windows, but I need it in android app.

I've try to use a relative ImageView and keep changing it's spot, but the main thread will ANR.
Second, I try to add it on the canvas, but it will have ghost when the icon move because I can't clear the screen. If I clear the screen, the whole view will be black.

Do anyone have experience on this kind of function?

---

#### Solved

Fixed it in mixed cursor and background color together, so I don't need another ImageView to fit in.

Answer (score 3):

Surround your surfaceView with a FrameLayout in your xml Layout. Then add your icon to the same FrameLayout. Make sure they are placed below the surface view so they get drawn on top of it.

```
<FrameLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/surfaceView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></SurfaceView>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
            <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Try replacing the buttons with your icon or images ..

Comment: Don't get what you are trying to present. I need an icon moving around above the surfaceview and won't have any ghost affected the surfaceview. Changing icon position can only be done on main thread that will cause ANR.